# Heroku Deployment from multiple win7 64 machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, ssh, rubymine

First of all, I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7070178/heroku-deployment-from-multiple-computers) but I still have problems with deploying from multiple machines.

From work everything works like a charm, but from home-machine I have problem pushing to same Heroku app. Both machines are Win7 64, IDE is Rubymine (jumping between integrated git gui and terminal - but no problems with that), Ruby200 and devkit both 32 and 64 (but on separate machines), .ssh keys in C:/users/.ssh/ (on both machines). Git stuff is also working like a charm on both machines. Same heroku acc.

On home machine when I `$ heroku keys` it lists 2 keys like it should (for work and home machine). Then when I `$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:my-app.git` I get fatal saying that I already have that remote repository on this machine. I check for remotes `$ git remote -v` and it lists 2 reps (both github and heroku), like it should, but when I `$ git push heroku` I get:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried deleting keys, generating new ones both with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and `heroku keys:add` to create after previously removing one and with no luck. Even added it with `heroku keys:add C:/path-to-ssh.pub` if that specificity even mater.

I know that I can 'cheat' this out with DropBox but I'd rather avoid them and go this way, pulling from Github. Thank you in advance, if more info is needed I will provide it.

**Edit**: I tried `$ heroku create project-with-another-name` to create heroku app with same code and it goes through. After I check for that remote via `$ git remote -v` I don't see it (only old ones), but when I tried to add it with `$ git remote add heroku ...`, it said to me that remote allready exist and I can see it in Heroku dashboard. `$ git push heroku master` gives me same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
# Generate key 
ssh-keygen -t rsa 

# Start of ssh-agent (I missed this step and
# it didn't added key to my machine even though it 
# created file. In order to do: ssh-add C:/path/to/id_rsa_key 
# I needed to start ssh-agent) 
eval $(ssh-agent)

# Then add private key
ssh-add C:/path/to/id_rsa_key 

cd C:/project

# And finaly send public key to heroku
heroku keys:add C:/path/to/id_rsa_key.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be an issue with the local `git` repos on your system, and how they communicate with the `remote` `Heroku` repo.

The issue will either be with the `ssh keys` on your system, or the `remote repos` your computer will have (and how you're able to communicate with `Heroku` properly).

--

**Fix**

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626944/heroku-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-reposito), you may wish to use the following:

> Really all I had to do was follow these steps:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys
>
> First you have to create a key:
>
> `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
>
> Second you have to add the key to Heroku:
>
> `heroku keys:add`

--

If that doesn't work, I would [get rid of the local git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514054/how-do-i-delete-a-local-repository-in-git) & then create a new remote one for use with Heroku:

```
delete the .git repo for your local app
```

In the `parent` / `apps` directory, run `git init [folder_name]`

Inside the app folder directly, you can then run `git@heroku.com:project.git`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but solution was Git Bash. Still can't push from Rubymine terminal to Heroku, it doesn't mater that my keys are ok and repos visible.

Comment: Update: Git Bash, started ssh-agent, generated ssh via keygen. The thing is that I needed to add id_rsa via `ssh-add path` and then send id_rsa.pub to heroku with `heroku keys:add path`. Crucial thing was `ssh-add`. Probably will work in Rubymine too.